# Add text and image into button at center android

Tags: android, android-button, input-button-image

I am beginner to android development and I am developing small android application. In my application I m using button. but contains image and text. everything is working fine only thing is that my text displayed at center of button and image at end of button what I want image and text both at center ..
My Button code looks like ...

```
  <Button
                android:id="@+id/signup_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="48dip"
                 android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
                 android:layout_marginLeft="1dip"
                 android:background="@drawable/help_screen_buttons"
                 android:text="Sign up"
                 android:textColor="@color/maroon_font"
                 android:alpha="0.8" 
                 android:textSize="22dip"
                 android:drawableLeft="@drawable/tw_br"/>
```

He I am only able to set image at left right top  bottom position but not at center ..
S how to display that image and text at center of button...
Need help...
thank you...

Answer (score 0):

I hope it's useful to you:

```
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/startTelemoteButton" 
    android:text="@string/start_telemote"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:width="fill_parent"
    android:height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: Hi hcd thank you for reply. I tried this but this will not display my image and text at center ...any other solution .. Thank you

Comment: android:src="@drawable/help_screen_buttons"   try this

Comment: Hi HCD thank you reply again.. @drawable/help_screen_button is my drawable xml file in which i defined some background color and some rounded corner. Is it make some change if I make it as src. I will try this as will.

Comment: when i use it as src it not applying that to my button.. Any other solution.. Thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use image button

```xml
 <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/image" />
```